# PJSIP cross compilation linker error unresolvable relocation

Tags: linux, cross-compilation, software-compilation

I'm trying to write a very small, very simple project using PJSIP. But I'm already stuck on the first step, incorporating PJSIP in my project. I'm trying to build and compile on a Ubuntu 14.04 system using an arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc cross compiler. For the coding itself I'm using Eclipse CDT, but the crosscompiling part is working in a normal order.

I downloaded de pjproject-2.3 folder to my system, configured it with this command:

```
   ./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf CFLAGS='--sysroot=/home/david/rpi/rootfs' LDFLAGS='--sysroot=/home/david/rpi/rootfs'
```

The /home/david/rpi/rootfs folder is where I copied the rootsystem of my Pi. I then ran 'make dep' and 'make'. I copied all the static libraries *.a to my Eclipse project folder and added the libraries to the linker (-l).

But when I want to build I get the following error:

```
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -L"/home/david/workspace/VoIPBenchmark" -L/home/david/rpi/rootfs/usr/lib -L/home/david/rpi/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --sysroot=/home/david/rpi/rootfs/ -o "VoIPBenchmark"  ./src/SipImplemantation.o ./src/SipImplementationPJ.o ./src/Timer.o  ./main.o   -lpjsua2-arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf -lpjsua-arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf -lpjsip-ua-arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf -lpjsip-simple-arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf -lpjsip-arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf -lpjsdp-arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf -lpjmedia-audiodev-arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf -lportaudio-arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf -lpjmedia-codec-arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf -lpjmedia-arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf -lspeex-arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf -lgsmcodec-arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf -lsrtp-arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf -lilbccodec-arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf -lresample-arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf -lpjnath-arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf -lpjlib-util-arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf -lpj-arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf -lpthread -lm -lrt -lasound -llinphone
/home/david/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/david/workspace/VoIPBenchmark/libsrtp-arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf.a(ctr_prng.o)(.text+0x8c): unresolvable R_ARM_ABS32 relocation against symbol `ctr_prng'
/home/david/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [VoIPBenchmark] Error 1
```

I googled some and tried to add -fPIC to the CFLAG in the ./configure step above, recopied the libraries, but without result. Does anyone know what this message is saying me, and better yet, knows a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been resolved. I was using a library that also linked to the srtp library, this evidently conflicted. So I am now not using the library that causes the problem.